# Is it a waste of money if I buy a multi-effect pedal when I have an amp which has built-in multi effects?

Tags: amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I have the [Nux Mighty Space](https://www.nuxaudio.com/mightyspace.html) desktop amp, which I like very much. For a reasonable price, this 30W comes with wireless module, foot switch, ability to connect via USB, and built-in effects.

The tones that I can get out of the Nux is limited due to similar [IR](https://blog.andertons.co.uk/learn/what-is-a-guitar-amp-impulse-response)s.

Now, I would like to buy a multi-effect pedal to expand my range of tones. However, I am a bit hesitant because maybe I can already get approximate tones from the amp itself and buying an extra processor would be a waste of money.

Would it be within reason to buy an extra multi-effect pedal as a support, or am I being too wasteful?

Comment: Is the tone selection limited to the IRs? To me it looks like it has emulation for most imaginable types of effects

Comment: The tone selection is definitely more than only IRs, but the IRs (and also amps) being too similar limits the tone variety.

Comment: This is why I didn't ask about the amp or cabinet selection but the effects. If the problem is the amp model and not the effects, I'm not sure how external multi-effect pedal would help.

Comment: I don't have a clear answer for that. My best approximation is; a multi-effect pedal has more effect and IR variety, and some of them also have an expression pedal with them. As I've said, I'm not sure whether that would be an unnecessary purchase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedals can be turned on and off by stomping on them during a live performance giving you more control and feel to your tracks. Setting the effects by hand on the amp is ok but if you're playing live you need a pedal.